# ImpalaJDBC41 - insert adds space char on the end of string, when contains "+"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, impala, kudu

I use *ImpalaJDBC41* to make inserts on kudu tables. The problem is when string contains "+", then inserted string is suffixed by space char. For example value is "ABC+", then column value is "ABC+ ".

Insert is made by *org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert*

Column type is STRING

**Dependencies**:

- Kudu: 1.5.0-cdh5.13.0
- Spring Boot: 2.0.5.RELEASE
- ImpalaJDBC41: 2.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Upgrade ImpalaJDBC41 to 2.6.15.1017 helped